# Fastapi returns 404 when accessing URL in the browser

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I am learning `fastapi` and created the sample following application:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/hello")
async def hello_world():
   return {"message": "hello_world"}

if __name__== "__main__":
   uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)
```

The server starts fine but when I test the `url` in browser I am getting the following error:

> {"detail": "Not Found"}

and this error in the log:

> "GET / HTTP /" 404 Not Found

I noticed another weird problem, when I make some error its not detecting the error and still starting the server. For example if I change the function like the following:

```
@app.get("/hello")
async def hello_world():
   print (sample)
   return {"message": "hello_world"}
```

It should have thrown the error:

> NameError: "sample" not defined

but it still is starting the server. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: The response `{"detail": "Not Found"}` is valid since you have accessed the URL ***`/`*** (the root URL), but in your app, you don't have any route to serve the same. In that case, you must've to access the `/hello` path. The second error is obvious in Python since you didn't define any variable named `sample` in the program context.

Comment: Since the code in your second example never runs (you never called `/hello` as described in your question), it will never be detected as non-existant. The variable isn't resolved before it's actually needed.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1:  It doesn't work. You code a handler for path `/hello`. But you are testing path `/` which is not configured.

Question 2: You didn't define the variable `sample`.

Comment: Just as feedback, I don't think answering with 'of course..' is very supportive. Everyone makes simple mistakes, especially when learning.

Answer (score 2):

always add the trailing slash after the path, had the same issue, took me hours to debug

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error. It is so stupid (for me)

I followed https://davidefiocco.github.io/streamlit-fastapi-ml-serving/

then access to http://0.0.0.0:8000/, then this `{"detail": "Not Found"}` occurred, too

but with `8000/docs`, everything was fine

> and then visit http://localhost:8000/docs with a web browser to
> interact with the FastAPI-generated documentation, which should look a
> bit like this

author wrote a function only for `/segmentation` (and may be for `/docs` in somewhere); there was no function for `/`